# How to associate .mp3 files in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to play an mp3 file based on a list view item click however based on my code went I run my app this window appears and so due to lack of an audio option I really don't know which one of these I need to select in order to associate my .mp3 files.

```
mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            //When clicked, go to specific activity
            if (position == 0) {
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                }
                try {
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("chimes.mp3");
                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to associate anything this is only used to OPEN the file on the host machine, has nothing to do with the device.

Answer (score 1):

you can drag and drop mp3 file in res folder android studio automatically dectect it