# I can't add mp3 to android studio project directory

Tags: android, mp3

This is basically an extension of this question

[How to associate .mp3 files in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257492/how-to-associate-mp3-files-in-android-studio/32463445#32463445)

I tried to add an .mp3 file to android studio for use in an app

a menu popped up as in the link's question, which wasn't clearly answered, however, unlike them, I clicked java, and that was completely the wrong thing to do.

NOW my .mp3 file is no longer in the raw directory where I put it, and I can't add it again either. It says Error: cannot create class file when I do.

No idea how to fix, please help

//Edit: here is more information to help clarify a few things

The raw directory is empty

adding .mp3 files to ANY directory is impossible because the file type .mp3 is registered as a java class but cannot resolve, thus creating an error.

I need to know how to un-register .mp3 files in android studio

//Edit: Update as I work on it and discover things:
The .mp3 file IS in the raw directory and can even be used in applications that correctly call it, HOWEVER android studio doesn't display it and won't allow me to add more .mp3 files via drag-and-drop. I can add files by going through my computer

Comment: Delete the MP3 file that you erroneously added previously. Then, try adding it again.

Answer (score 0):

Per [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), first delete the file.

If you still have problems, you can try what I've used for an assets folder in gradle.  You should be able to replace assets folder with raw, if you like. You should also be able to change it location in the folder hierarchy if you like and modify the folder location in gradle.build file.  In the directory structure, I do something like this.

```
app
   src
      assets
            yourfile.mp3
```

Then within your gradle.build script for the Module : app add the following in the defaultConfig section.

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.your.app"
    ...
}

    sourceSets {
    main {

        assets.srcDirs = ['/src/assets']

    }
}
```

So you can replace assets with raw in my example.

Comment: I don't think you understand... the file is no longer anywhere, furthermore it CAN'T be re-added as it gives me an error when I try. The problem seems to be with Android Studio itself not the project or the build (I haven't attempted a build)

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle` add the following block:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['/res/raw']
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead, right-click to res folder > add new Directory > name is "raw" > paste there your mp3 file. You should see it listed on the project tree. This was my solution.